# MYSQL: Getting the first letter of each word in a field

Tags: mysql

I need to query to get the first letter of each word from a field.
Flora would be F
Fort Wayne would be FW

Other two word examples would be Gas City, South Bend, so it's words of variable length.

```
$query="SELECT id,
    (CASE
            WHEN toggle = 1 THEN concat(city,' ',school)
            WHEN toggle = 2 THEN concat(school,' (',substring(city,1,1),')')
            ELSE school
    END) as schools
    FROM a_schools
    ORDER BY schools
    ";
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Not sure.  The most current, I presume.

Comment: It makes a *big* difference to how easy it is to answer the question. What do you get if you `SELECT @@version`?

Comment: version 5.6.41-84.1 -- so not the most current, I would guess.

Comment: @Strawberry that doesn't really help me.  While the answer might be there isn't an easy answer, it's not like it's that complicated to understand the problem.  If it was just needing the first letter of any field, I would have 3-4 ways of getting it.  I wondered from those more experience than me, how do I go about getting the first letter of each word in a field.

Comment: @Jwrbloom would there ever be 2 spaces in your field data (3 or more "words"), like `Fort Wayne Indiana`? If there would be there's nothing really you can do to get the first letter of each "word". If there will at most be 1 space in your field (only 2 "words"), like `Denver Colorado` that would be possible, but not if there could be 2 or more spaces (3 or more "words") in your field.

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Given the current data, no.  Two words would be the most in this column, so just one space.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak You shouldn't tell people that something is impossible. You never know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_letterOfEachWord;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION f_letterOfEachWord(p_text varchar(255)) 
RETURNS varchar(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE result varchar(255);
    DECLARE tmp varchar(255);
    SET tmp = p_text;
    SET result = SUBSTRING(tmp, 1, 1);
    WHILE (LOCATE(' ', tmp) > 0) DO
        SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(tmp, LOCATE(' ', tmp) + 1, 1));
        SET tmp = SUBSTRING(tmp, LOCATE(' ', tmp) + 1);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN UPPER(result);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and use it like this:

```
mysql> select f_letterOfEachWord('asdf');
+----------------------------+
| f_letterOfEachWord('asdf') |
+----------------------------+
| A                          |
+----------------------------+

mysql> select f_letterOfEachWord('asdf qwer');
+---------------------------------+
| f_letterOfEachWord('asdf qwer') |
+---------------------------------+
| AQ                              |
+---------------------------------+

mysql> select f_letterOfEachWord('asdf qwer yxcv');
+--------------------------------------+
| f_letterOfEachWord('asdf qwer yxcv') |
+--------------------------------------+
| AQY                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
```